# Appropriate HTTP response code when previous action is required

Tags: http, rest

I'm developing a REST API for a system in which, for the sake of the example, exist `Users` and `Maps`. `Maps` can be downloaded, commented and voted by `Users`.

When `Users` download `Maps` a relationship is created between them. Now, when `Users` want to comment and vote `Maps` I check if that relationship exists, returning an error in case it doesn't so clients know it's missing.

Which HTTP code should I return in this case, to let clients know previous action is required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error case you describe sounds like it describes an bad request from the client.  Thus it probably belongs in the 4xx family.  Looking over the choices, 409 Conflict seems to be the best match.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html describes it as follows:

**409 Conflict**

*The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the resource. This code is only allowed in situations where it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request. The response body SHOULD include enough information for the user to recognize the source of the conflict. Ideally, the response entity would include enough information for the user or user agent to fix the problem; however, that might not be possible and is not required.*

Of course the HTTP response code alone will not be enough for clients to act upon.  As the above states, the response entity should provide details about what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

A `409 Conflict` is probably the closest fit. It's defined thusly in RFC 2616:

> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current
>   state of the resource. This code is only allowed in situations where
>   it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and
>   resubmit the request. The response body SHOULD include enough
>
> information for the user to recognize the source of the conflict.
>   Ideally, the response entity would include enough information for the
>   user or user agent to fix the problem; however, that might not be
>   possible and is not required.

Some people use `400 Bad Request`, but I wouldn't do that because that error signifies that the server doesn't understand what the client wants to do. It sounds like in your case, the server understands but cannot fulfill the request.

The other option is `403 Forbidden`, but this is less appropriate than a `409` because it usually is used in response to not having enough privileges to view a particular resource (and the spec indicates that the request should not be repeated).

Comment: Both answers are exactly what I wanted to read, but I'm accepting the other answer because of posting time. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. It's totally crazy that after 3 hours, 2 people posted responses within 1 minute of each other. :)

Comment: Yeah, I was totally shocked it happened :D